# Function and Mechanism of Height Genes

Tags: genetics, epigenetics

I have an inquiry regarding the exact function of height genes.

To my knowledge, although they are heavily regulated by epigenetic factors, height genes can have either an "on" or an "off" allele, and the probability of the person being "tall" shows positive correlation with the number of "on" height genes alleles he has.

However, I could not find any resources showing the exact function or mechanism of these genes' function. Do these genes code for a specific protein when they are "on"? And if there are any, how do these proteins increase the probability of the person being "tall"?

Thank you.

Comment: Can you link to the sources that postulate "on/off" genes or to what some of those genes might be? That would help potential answerers follow the paper trail to the function of those genes.

Comment: There is no such thing as "height genes". There are, however, genes that have a quantitative effect on height, such as SHOX which interacts with bone development. Others have a dominant effect, like EGF3, which causes achondroplasia when it is mutated. However, the expression of genes that control growth is highly regulated by environment and epigenetic factors. It would really help if you linked some kind of source, or some group of genes.